# Backing up System Image of Primary Drive to External HDD and Files on Secondary Hard Drive to Same External HDD?

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, backup, external-hard-drive, data-transfer

I have a weird use case:

**I have two drives in my PC: C drive (1TB nvme ssd) and D drive (different 1 TB nvme ssd).**

C drive has windows, d drive has personal files.

**I want to create a complete image of the C drive onto my external USB HDD (4tb) and also back up my the files on my D drive to the remaining space on the same external HDD.**

Is this possible?

I know tools like AOMEI Backupper exist, but these format and remove any preexisting partitions before making a system image.

Comment: You can make *complete* images of *both* drives at the same time, which is much more reliable than backing up only selected system files (key files are sometimes omitted) and much more rapid than backing up file-by-file from the secondary drive. Imaging tools such as Macrium Reflect can be set to image only sectors with data, so it only takes up as much space as is in use.  In addition, those image files keep the same structure as the original file system, and can be *mounted* as drives to access data and even run applications.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up using Macrium reflect and, for now, just cloned my C drive to the USB HDD. So I have roughly 3 TB left over. Is it possible to go back and run Macrium Reflect again and clone my D drive to the remaining unallocated 3 TB?

Comment: Sure! Just name the file for the D: image differently from C:, so that it doesn't overwrite it. Also, be careful: Reflect can be set to automatically delete older files if there's not enough room for the new image. Be sure that you *disallow* that setting, to prevent the earlier image's deletion.